# access list by index in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to access an index position in list dynamically.

> {{ allAppsList.{{app.id}}.link }}

It is not working.

> {{ allAppsList.0.link }}

worked.

It should be some grammar issue. I google online, but didn't find anything helpful.

BTW:
This is what I want to do if using in Java.

> int index = app.id;
>
> String link = appList[index].getLink();

Answer (score 2):

You can't do such a thing in django template, But it's not impossible also.

If you are really into this, you can create a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).
The implementation would be easy, Just pass the list and `index` to your `custom filter` and do exactly what you would do with `Java`.

Start to [writing custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

Answer (score 0):

You can't lookup lists like that in Django's template language - it's a design decision. Method calls, dictionary keys, attribute calls and list indexes are all handled by the `.` (dot) notation. [Have a look at the docs for more about how Django decides on what to do when it encounters a dot](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables)